# Android: Reset Class Variables when logout in MainActivity

Tags: java, android

just wanna ask you of a better way to reset all the class variables of an MainActivity when the user wants to logout than the one i am presenting here.

```
    public class MainActivity
            extends AppCompatActivity{


        public static String userId;
        private ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        private ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        private Prefs prefs;


        private void logOut(){
            userId = null;
            list1 = new ArrayList<>();
            // Helperlist of all the Ids in "friends"
            list2 = new ArrayList<>();
            prefs = null;

            onCreate(null);
        }
    }
```

The class variables userId, list1, list2 and prefs are set somewhere else for a specific user. If the user logs out, it should be "null"ed.
The Problem here is that everytime i want to add a class variable, it has to be "null"ed in logOut() as well. This could be an easy source of errors if I am going add more and more class variables. Can you give me a better way of doing this?

Thanks,

Ayox

Comment: The scope of class variables ends  when the class is destroyed. If you are maintaining logout and login in same activity then there is no other way as far as i know except to nullify them.

Answer (score 1):

A recommendation, calling Android lifecycle methods by yourself is considered a "bad practice".

I would recommend you that extract from `onCreate` method all your custom initializations to a custom method and then call it from `logOut()`

Hope it helps!

Comment: why is it a bad practice? or whats the downside of it?

Comment: Because they are callback methods and they are called by the Android system in determinate points of the execution of your app, for example, when an Activity is created or when is restored.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Reflection to reset all the instance variables. Its not an elegant solution but it will ensure all variables are nullified.

```
Field[] fields = object.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
for (Field f : fields) {
  f.setAccessible(true);
  f.set(object, null);
}
```

Comment: Thats a really nice and easy way. Why is it not considered "elegant"?

Comment: Because reflection makes your code a bit slower. So its a trade off between speed and convenience.

Comment: Thanks Rick; I want to add that there are also security restrictions and exposure of internals: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to not use `static` for class variables (as in the case of `userId`).

Also, since your class variables are storing session-related data, you can instead store it in `SharedPreferences`, and simply call `prefs.clear()` on logout, where the `clear()` method can be defined as something like `SharedPreferences#edit().clear().apply();`

Comment: static: yeah i have to change that, is on my todolist
sharedPreferences: wont help or is a bit complicated, since i also have variables from own created Objects, but i will consider it, if there is no better solution

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any better solution than implementing a `Closeable` interface and clear your variables in the `close()` method, then call it when you log out.
And I'd suggest to rename/remove the `logOut` method since it does something else, and probably it's responsibilities lies in another class.